# list comprehension python with multiple variables

Tags: python

Hello am new to python i need to ask it is possible for someone to write this code for me in normal conversion and not using list comprehension found the code online as i dont understand the part of a[i]

```
a = [[1, 9, 2, 6], [5, 1, 10, 7], [9, 1, 2, 4, 5], [9, 8, 9, 8, 3], [7, 4, 5, 8, 4], [7, 3, 5, 9, 6]]

b = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i%2]
print(b)
```

also is it possible to use list comprehension on multiple variable like the below and if so please show me thank you.

```
RANKS = 'A 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K'.split()
        whole_deck, SPADE,HEARTS, DIAMONDS, CLUBS = [],[],[],[],[]
        for cards in RANKS:
            HEARTS.append(cards)
            DIAMONDS.append(cards)
            CLUBS.append(cards)
            SPADE.append(cards)
```

Comment: This should be two separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is how to deal with multiple lists in comprehension notation.
The point is to add a nested form of comprehension notation to the comprehension notation that takes out the first list.

```
[[y for y in x if y % 2] for x in a]
[[1, 9], [5, 1, 7], [9, 1, 5], [9, 9, 3], [7, 5], [7, 3, 5, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the loop "normally":

```py
a = [[1, 9, 2, 6], [5, 1, 10, 7], [9, 1, 2, 4, 5], [9, 8, 9, 8, 3], [7, 4, 5, 8, 4], [7, 3, 5, 9, 6]]
b = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if i%2:
        b.append(a[i])
print(b)
```